# use ng-controller in script tag with text/ng-template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use `ng-controller` in script tag witch is a template and has `ng-template` directive
i don't know why it's now working

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal-5" >
<div ng-controller="reserveModalCtrl">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="currentModal.close();"
                aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Rserve Shortcode</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field-1" class="control-label">Shortcode</label>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-1" 
                                 value="30570" disabled>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field-2" class="control-label">Company</label>
                    <div id="field-2">
                        <select class="form-control" 
                                ng-model="currentShortCode.companyId">
                            <option ng-repeat="company in companies track by $index" 
                                   value="{{company._id}}"> {{company.companyName 
                                   + ' (' + company.companyLatinName + ')'}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Until</label>
                <div>
                    <div class="date-and-time">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentShortCode.date" 
                               class="form-control datepicker" 
                               data-format="D, dd MM yyyy">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentShortCode.time" 
                               class="form-control timepicker" data-template="dropdown" 
                               data-show-seconds="true" data-default-time="11:25 AM" 
                               data-show-meridian="true" data-minute-step="5" 
                               data-second-step="5" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" 
                ng-click="currentModal.close();">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" 
                ng-click="currentModal.dismiss();">Reserve</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller

```
app.controller('reserveModalCtrl', function ($scope, ShortCodeService) {
    $scope.companies    = ShortCodeService.companies;
    $scope.shortCodes   = ShortCodeService.shortCodes;
    $scope.test         = 'test';
});
```

when i use this on div element it's working but in this case not.

Comment: so you try `<script  ng-controller="reserveModalCtrl"`?

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Where is that `templateUrl` for the script tag being called in your code? Not enough information given. A demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) would also be helpful

Comment: @charlietfl, i think OP try apply `ng-controller` directive to _script_ tag, and see that this not working, but when he moe to div inside - all work

Comment: @Grundy I don't see how that would work. `ng/template` is used to pass ID to a `templateUrl` in directive, routing or `ng-include` and the `ng-controller` would never be exposed if it was on script tag

Comment: @charlietfl, i think OP just try it :-)

Comment: thanks to every body, finally i did this, it's a modal template and i injected my controller in $modal options as controller and it's worked fine,

Comment: and here is the link that helped me to solve this, https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the [script](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) directive says that you can use it to:

> Load the content of a  element into $templateCache, so that the template can be used by **ngInclude**, **ngView**, or **directives**. The type of the  element must be specified as text/ng-template, and a cache name for the template must be assigned through the element's id, which can then be used as a directive's templateUrl.

So to actually render the template, you must either map it to a route when configuring the router (either standard ngRoute or ui-router) or include it with ngInclude (for example, `<div ng-include="modal-5"></div>`) or as the templateUrl attribute of a directive definition object.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, i found my solution here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/